# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'CodeMirror')

Tags: google-chrome, next.js, localhost, codemirror

I seem to be facing an issue with my NextJS (13) app. Somehow Chrome gives me the next error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'CodeMirror')

It happens with every entry/event to any input field in my app and until yesterday i didn't have any issues. I haven't made any changes to my code that could have had an effect on these input fields. Safari and Firefox don't give me any errors.

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="title"
    defaultValue={post.title}
    onChange={(e) => 
    setTitle(e.target.value)}
    placeholder="title"
/>
```

Also in my deployment on Vercel the input fields work perfect in Chrome. So it seems to be limited to localhost/Chrome.

Hopefully someone understands more about whats happening here than i do.

Comment: I had the same problem even though I had no input fields. The problem was the https://www.enpass.io/ Chrome extension.

Answer (score 8):

remove the blackbox extension from chrome extension may

Answer (score 4):

Figured out what the problem was, had the blackbox extension installed in chrome. After removing this extension all my input fields worked fine again in localhost. Still is weird to me that it happened so sudden, especially since i got this extension for ages. But it fixed the issue.